# javascript : changing the whole style of a page when clicking the button

Tags: javascript

I made a keyboard with html and css.
I have a button in it and I want that when I push it, the other buttons change.(for example if it was 3, I want it to be # when I click on the button)

Comment: Use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to create a key/value pairing between the 3 and the #.

Comment: Welcome to SO, btw. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: @Andy  You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be a simple example .
when you push `change whole buttons` all the buttons will be #.

```js
const simpleButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.simple-button');
const lordButton = document.querySelector('.lord-button');

lordButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  simpleButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.textContent = "#";
  });
});
```

```css
.simple-button {
  background-color: #6366F1;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
 <button class="simple-button">3</button>
 <button class="simple-button">3</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />

<button class="lord-button">change whole buttons</button>
```